# Msi laptop: screen freezing

Tags: laptop, freeze

I bought a laptop 2 years ago:

- ***MSI GE62 6QD - C***
- ***Graphic: Nvidia GTX960M***

Since i bought it, I have this problem:

- While working,screen freezes like this:

[image: Pic1]

And everytime when this happens:I need to hold the power button to turn off and then turn up again the laptop.

Sometimes it happens 4 5 times in a day

Sometimes it doesn't happens for 2 or 3 days

How many times in 2 years?

I think:about 1000 times!

Really?What is the problem?

But when i'm playing games(with high graphics),it less happens.

Imagine:

- I'm playing a game for 100 hours,it can happen just 1 or 2 times!
- But when i'm coding or working(or watching movies) for 100 hours,it
  can happen 10 20 times!

**Note that**:

- I always play games while laptop plugged in

And it can fewer happens when laptop plugged in:

- While coding and plugged in: in 100 hours,it can happens 7 or 14
  times

And i don't think it's about the OS which i'm using.

- I used windows 10 about 1 year
- And also I'm using Linux for about 1 years

Can anybody tell me?

Where is the problem with my laptop?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind for me is a voltage problem with the batteries. I suggest you get them checked. If you have been having this problem since you bought it then it sounds like a problem with the hardware. Probably should have filed a warranty claim for repair when it first started after you bought it and before the warranty expired.

Comment: i sent for warranty,to repair...they didn't understand what is the problem...or they understood but they ignore the problem! idk ,  my ssd also failed 2 month ago too! i changed it... i don't think the problem is with my hardware! @RichardChambers